# Product saving very slow (takes minutes)

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, varnish

For several days my backend takes minutes for saving and generating products.

I have this message in my logs :

```
[2019-05-13 08:25:06] main.CRITICAL: Read timed out after 10 seconds {"method":"POST","url":"http://XXX/admin/catalog/product/save/type/simple/store/0/set/4/key/3f8d5c232e1008b42d7776c86bae57cbc8d6da89081040a13e0e01b667a45deb/back/edit","invalidateInfo":{"server":"[object] (Zend\\Uri\\Uri: http://localhost:6082/)","tagsPattern":"((^|,)cat_p_1168(,|$))"}} []
```

I'm on magento 2.2.5

PS : I'm using varnish cache.

I have this error after a few minutes :

> Error 503 Backend fetch failed
>
> Backend fetch failed Guru Meditation:
>
> XID: 1742759
>
> Varnish cache server

Anone facing the same issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change indexing settings to `Update on schedule` and do indexing by ssh manually or setup the cron jobs to let Magento manage it on its own.

Comment: I'll try, can you explain why please ?

Comment: I hope your indexing mode is on "Update on Save" instead of "Update on schedule".  In this case, magento will try to do indexing activity for specific product with latest data which will go through lot of background process like capture and store latest info on various indexing tables. It is a time taking process and the time out error will happen easily whenever action triggered from browser. In other hand, update on schedule will trigger the reindex process via command cron job which will be always faster.

Comment: Ok thanks. Did that and some stuff (remove Varnish for a while), and it works. Thanks!